# Force a job to come in foreground when asked for user input

Tags: shell-script, job-control

I'm currently working on an audit-script for a huge platform. In the main-script we use traps and in one of the traps I ask the user for clean up the files. The script has no output in standard output, so running the script in the bg is obvious.

When sending a SIGQUIT to the bg-job it stops, and I have to put it manually in the foreground with `fg` to get the prompt.

*What I tried:*
I played around with `set -m` to active job control and put an `fg` into my trap-function.

With `set -m` my shell close after the script finished, without it I get debug-output, that my script doesn't have job control. Even with `set -m`, the job doesn't come into foreground.

For this, my questions are:

- Is it possible to force a job to come into foreground at some point?
- I know this is not the common way to use job-control inside a script. What is "best practise" for this?
- Is job-control inside a script only for sub-shells/child-processes or can I use it to control the job I started?

**Edit:**
as lcd047 suggested it is much more elegant to use `screen` or `tmux`, to keep the scripts clean and simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is job-control inside a script only for sub-shells/child-processes or can I use it to control the job I started?

Yes.  It's the parent shell that does the job control, you can't put the child process to foreground from within itself.

**Edit:** You can however still do it like this:

- Child script:

  ```
  #! /bin/sh
  ...
  trap "kill -s USR1 $PPID" TTOU
  ...
  echo -n Cleanup?
  read yn </dev/tty
  ...
  ```
- Parent script:

  ```
  #! /bin/sh
  ...
  trap "fg %1" USR1
  ...
  child &
  ...
  wait
  ...
  ```

This installs a signal handler for `SIGTTOU` in the child, and another
signal handler for `SIGUSR1` in the parent.  When the child tries to output something to the terminal it receives a `SIGTTOU`.  It then sends a `SIGUSR1` to the parent, which in turn runs `fg %1` and puts the child to foreground.

The above assumes `%1` to be the child process.  In practice you probably have a single process in background anyway.

Comment: absolutly solves my issue! Is it common to do like this or should I just find another solution in genereal without job-control?

Comment: It's probably not very common, and prone to subtle complications (and bugs).  Personally I'd just run it in `tmux` or `screen` in a pane, and not bother with background.